# Start Docker container on MacOS system boot

Tags: mysql, macos, docker, docker-container, macos-high-sierra

I am running Docker 17.09.0-ce and have a container called

`new-mysql`

> Container ID c7fee123ec9f

It's a pain to have to start that container manually every time I want to use it, so I wondered if there is a way to do this on system boot.

I don't want to kill this container as it works perfectly, i'd just simply like to tweak the settings to start automatically on system boot (or when Docker starts).

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
docker run --restart unless-stopped new-mysql
```

You can find more detailed information here:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/start-containers-automatically/

Comment: Thanks, however that does not work. I had originally came across that command previous why I tried this, but it gives me: `Unable to find image 'new-mysql:latest' locally` and `docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for new-mysql, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.`. I definitely have the correct container name. It doesn't work with either the container name _or_ the container ID.

Answer (score 0):

Type in `docker ps` to see the image of the docker container.

[image]

In this case, the image is named 'microsoft/mssql-server-linux', use the image name instead of the container name: `docker run --restart=unless-stopped microsoft/mssql-server-linux`.

This should work for you ;)

Comment: Hmm, yeah I tried that with the image (`mysql:5.7`) but it's just stuck as a STATUS of `Restarting (1) 2 seconds ago`. NAMES `gifted_hopper`. No further forward, unfortunately.

Comment: I can't seem to get rid of that restart policy now. I have tried `docker update --restart=no my-container` to no avail.

Comment: A restart of Docker itself killed that strange container which was trying to restart itself. I have no idea where the `gifted_hopper` container came from, but it's not the solution to this problem i'm afraid.

Comment: Hmm... I'm very sorry I were not able to help you, I really don't know why this doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Commit the container to a new image, to preserve the container state:

```
docker commit c7fee123ec9f launch/mysql-image
```

The run the new image with the extra arguments

```
docker run --restart=unless-stopped launch/mysql-image --name phoenix-mysql
```